# Game not exiting in AndEngine

Tags: android, andengine

On exit button of my game

I used

```
 System.runFinalizersOnExit(true);
 System.exit(0);
```

I have also tried only

```
finish();
```

on game exit but its not working the game exits and restarts again. Can any one help me with this problem what is the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android (and some other mobile platforms, plus web) do not have a concept of "exiting" the app. User just goes to another app's activity and the system (eventually) clears the process from memory.

When your Activity is leaved it gets notified via [lifecycle callbacks](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/activities.html#Lifecycle). There you can do cleanup if necessary.

[Is quitting an application frowned upon?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2033914/quitting-an-application-is-that-frowned-upon)